# Start an .exe file with Python as Administrator without asking for password?

Tags: python, admin, exe, administrator

I have a problem with runing an `.exe` file with administrator rights.

I also tried:

```
subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'myfile.exe'])
```

But then I have to enter a password.
Is there any chance to leave that out?

Answer (score 0):

run the shell as administrator and you will be able to call other things as administrator from that shell

Comment: you might want to ask superuser.com @user2551335

Answer (score 0):

Just put admin password in place specified, or leave empty quotes if there is no admin password.

`subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'ADMIN_PASS','myfile.exe'])`